# Coloring rows in table

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I have a problem with coloring table. I would like to color one row, but when I use `\rowcolor`, then vertical lines among colums disappear (or they become thinner). Is there any possibility of solving this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Yes, don't use vertical lines. With or without colored rows, is always a bad idea. See for example [here](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf).

Comment: It is possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180496/colortbl-row-column-color-overwrite-hline-on-screen#comment417038_180496, apart from Fran's statement about vertical lines, I think it is an pdf viewer issue

Comment: The problem is probably a pdf viewer problem and is already discussed in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180496/colortbl-row-column-color-overwrite-hline-on-screen#comment417038_180496