# Create a table with once- and twice-hatched regions and curly braces

Tags: tables, braces

I try to make the next table with this hatching, dashed lines of cells and curly braces in Latex:
[image]
I have seen a lot of different examples on this website: [Set table background hatched and shaded using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/set-table-background-hatched-and-shaded-using-tikz) (hatching), [Tables with colored cells and dashed lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125467/tables-with-colored-cells-and-dashed-lines) (dashed lines of cells), [How to mix coloring and hatching in the same cell in a tabular environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455586/how-to-mix-coloring-and-hatching-in-the-same-cell-in-a-tabular-environment?rq=1) (hatching+coloring).

But I haven't find hatching cells with both type of hatching (north east + north west) and whole combinations of features, which is needed in my example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns}

\graphicspath{{pictures/}}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] {#1;}}
\makeatother
% end of Andrew's code

\newcommand\HatchedCell[4][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \fill[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (0,1.9ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (0pt,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand\HatchedCellw[4][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \fill[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (0,1.9ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (0pt,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%

}%

\begin{document}


\HatchedCell{start3}{end3}{%
  pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}

\HatchedCellw{start4}{end4}{%
  pattern color=black!70,pattern=north west lines}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
& $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & \hspace{0.4in} & $a_i$ & $a_i+1$ & $a_i+2$ & \hspace{0.4in} & $B$\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
\ldelim\{{5}{1mm}[$k<l_i$]  $1$ & & & & & & & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start4}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{} &\multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start4}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{} \rdelim\}{9}{1mm}[$k<j-a_i$]\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$2$ & $\infty$ & & & & & & & & $\infty$ \\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$3$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & & & & & &\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
\multicolumn{1}{:c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{$\infty$} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{$\infty$} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{$\infty$} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{:c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{}\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$l_i-1$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start4}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start4}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start4}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{} & & $\infty$ \\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$l_i$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start4}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{}  & & & & $\infty$ \\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$l_i+1$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & & & & &\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
\multicolumn{1}{:c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{:c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{}\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$B-a_i-1$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & & & & &\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$B-a_i$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & & & & &\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$B-a_i+1$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & & & & &\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
\multicolumn{1}{:c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{:c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c:}{}\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
$B$ & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start3}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{} &  & & & &\\
\cdashline{5-5} \hhline{----~----}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\upbracefill}\\[-1ex]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\scriptstyle k>j$}\\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

In the places, where twice-heating is needed I put symbol of infinity, but it's better to look on the picture above.

P.S.: Sorry for my English. It's not good enough.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Just a question: will there be  text in the hatched cells?

Comment: Hello! :) There will be no text in hatched cells, just hatching!

Answer (score 4):

I propose a solution based on `tabularx, bigdelim` and `pstricks-add`
 The general idea is to define empty nodes in the relevant cells, shifted to the lower left corner of the cell it belongs to, then to link these cells by closed polygonal paths, which are filled with one of the hatch fill styles.

```
\documentclass[t12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow, bigdelim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{$}X<{$}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newcommand{\mynode}[1]{\pnode[-6.2pt, -5.6pt]{#1}}
\newcommand{\mycline}{\cline{2-5}\cdashline{6-6}[2.5pt/2pt]\cline{7-9}\cdashline{10-10}[2.5pt/2pt]\cline{11-11}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\dashlinedash}{3pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{2pt}
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|>{$}p{15mm}<{$}|*{9}{Y|}l}
    \mycline
    & &\mynode{H01} 1 & 2 & 3 & \mynode{D0} ... & a_i & a_i + 1 & \mynode{H07} a_i + 2 & \mynode{H08} ... & B & \mynode{B1}\\
    \mycline
     \ldelim\{{5.2} {3.3em}[$ k < l_i $]& 1 &\mynode{H11} & \mynode{H12}& & & & & \mynode{H17} & \mynode{H18} & &\hskip-0.33em\rdelim\}{9.4}{*}[ $ k < j-a_i $]\\
    \mycline
    & 2 & & \mynode{H22}& \mynode{H23} & & & & & \mynode{H28}& \mynode{H29}\\
    \mycline
    & 3 & & & \mynode{H33} & \mynode{D3} & & & & & \\
    \mycline
     & ⋮& & & & & & & & & \\
    \mycline
    & l_{i-1} & \mynode{H51}& & & \mynode{D5} & & & & & \mynode{H59} \\
    \mycline
    & l_i & & & & & & & & &\mynode{H69} & \mynode{B6}\\
    \mycline
    & l_{i + 1} & & & & & & & & & \\
    \mycline
     & ⋮ & \mynode{H81} & & & \mynode{D8} \mynode{H85} &\mynode{H86} & & & & \\
    \mycline
    & B-a_i - 1 & & & & \mynode{H95} & \mynode{H96} & \mynode{H97}& & &\mynode{H9a} & \mynode{B9}\\
    \mycline
    & B-a_i & & & & & \mynode{Ha6} & \mynode{Ha7} & \mynode{Ha8}& & \\
    \mycline
    & B-a_i + 1 & & & & & & \mynode{Hb7} & \mynode{Hb8} & \mynode{Hb9}& \\
    \mycline
   & ⋮ & & & & & & & \mynode{Hc8} & \mynode{Hc9} & \mynode{Hca} \\
    \mycline
   & B &\mynode{B} & & & & & & &\mynode{Hd9} & \mynode{Hda} \\
    \mycline 
        \end{tabularx}
    \psset{linestyle=none, hatchwidth=0.4pt, hatchsep=1.6pt}
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines] (H01)(H11)(H12)(H22)(H23)(H33)(D3)(D5)(H59)(H29)(H28)(H18)(H17)(H07)%(K) %
    \psset{fillstyle=hlines}
    \pspolygon(H51)(D5)(H85)(H86)(H96)(H97)(Ha7)(Ha8)(Hb8)(Hb9)(Hc9)(Hca)(Hda)(B)
    \pspolygon(H69)(B6)(B9)(H9a)
    \psset{fillstyle=crosshatch*,fillcolor=black, hatchcolor=white,hatchwidth=1.6pt,hatchsep=1.6pt, hatchangle=0}
    \pspolygon(H11)(H12)(H22)(H23)(H33)(D3)(D5)(H51)
    \pspolygon(H07)(H17)(H18)(H28)(H29)(H69)(B6)(B1)
    \psbrace[ref=c, nodesepB=0.5em, braceWidthInner=4pt, braceWidthOuter=6pt](B)(Hda){$k > j$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thousands thanks for your help!!! I really appreciate it! But I have some problems with running your program...

Comment: Thank you, Bernard for your program! I have solved the problem with launching your program and I have runned it. I use MikTeX. But I have questions about the picture of table: 1) Is there another picture of twice-hatched (cross-hatched) cell? I'm sorry, but this one look like grid instead of twice-hatched (cross-hatched) cell. 2) How can I change solid vertical lines to the dashed vertical lines between row "3" and "l_(i-1)", "l_(i+1)" and "B-a_i-1" and etc? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot compile with `pdflatex` (except with `auto-pst-pdf` and the switch `pdflatex --shell-escape`) because pdflatex cannot make the calculations required by postscript - you have to compile either the classic way, via `latex->dvips->pstopdf`, or with `xelatex`.

Comment: Hi, Bernard! Thanks for your quick answer! I handled this problem by using xelatex. There is such option in MikTeX.

Comment: For a twice-hatched area, you can use `\pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines](...)`, then again  with the other fill pattern: `\pspolygon[fillstyle=hlines](...)` (for the same polygon, of course).

Comment: I try to run program with \pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines]\pspolygon[fillstyle=hlines](H07)(H17)(H18)(H28)(H29)(H69)(B6)(B1) and  \pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines](\pspolygon[fillstyle=hlines](H07)(H17)(H18)(H28)(H29)(H69)(B6)(B1)) both variants are incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about LaTeX.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/175811)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/175811)